# Cosmology from within a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, black-holes, cosmological-constant

Suppose an astronaut is travelling "into" a black hole and has already passed the Schwarzschild boundary (as described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQZ3R81iyE0)). What will the universe look like to this astronaut, assuming he is equipped with the same technology as we have on Earth?

- Will the universe appear flat and anisotropic to him?
- When he measures the Cosmic Microwave Background, will he get the same picture as we do on Earth? With the same or with a different dipole direction?
- When he measures the Hubble constant and the percentage of "dark energy", will he get the same values as we do on Earth?

Comment: This isn't an answer, as you've specified 1915's GR as the version of Einsteinian relativity that you're using, but Einstein-Cartan Theory (worked out by Einstein in collaboration with the mathematician Ely Cartan in 1929) is claimed by Nikodem Poplawski to "avoid the singularity" by its assignment of a tiny spatial extent (a few orders of magnitude larger than the Planck length) to fermions.  The 2010-2021 papers elaborating his model can be found by his name on Cornell University's Arxiv site.  ECT requires rotation of the local universe:  Some evidence for it's been found, by Cai & Shamir.

Comment: The "papers" are actually preprints:  Many have been published.

Comment: When you fall through the horizon, you see the stars right behind you redshifted, but the stars at a certain angle blueshifted. The rest is self evident.